# Scrollable DataTables table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_dynamic.html) on DataTables to get a scrollable, searchable fixed height table. Here is my snippet of code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTables_paginate').DataTable({
    filter: true,
    info: false,
    scrollY: '25vh',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    language: {
      search: "_INPUT_",
      searchPlaceholder: "Search..."
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dataTables_filter {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTables_paginate">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have two issues with the code I have written so far. First of all, the `<thead>` seems to be detatched from the main body of the table wheras I would like it to all stay together.

Secondly, I have tried to left align the search box of the DataTable but I cannot get it to move over no matter what code I have used. Is there a way I can left align the search box and have it be the same width as the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the [CSS for datatables bootstrap](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) `dataTables.bootstrap.css` which can be found on the [CDN page](https://cdn.datatables.net/) of datatables for example. Including this fixes the problem with the header.

To apply a style to the filter / search box you should wrap it in a div, this can be done with the [dom option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) of datatables, check the snippet below for an example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTables_paginate').DataTable({
    filter: true,
    info: false,
    scrollY: '25vh',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    dom: '<"wrapper"f>lrtip',
    language: {
      search: "_INPUT_",
      searchPlaceholder: "Search..."
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper input {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTables_paginate">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Steve Jason Smith</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks. Being picky, do uo know what is causing the search box to not align with the left of the grid? I assume its just a margin or padding somewhere.. Is there also a way to change the fontsize of the search box?

Comment: @CBreeze some CSS sets the margin of the searchbox but you can overwrite that with your own CSS. I've update the snippet in my answer, I hope you get the idea.